# Indicator icons too small in gnome-flashback session

Tags: gnome, icons, indicator

I'm using laptop with HiDPI screen and Ubuntu 16.10. Default Ubuntu session looks fine.

In gnome-flashback session fonts look nice too, but application menu icons and indicator icons are too small and hard to read: [image: screenshot here].

I wonder if there is a way to make icons of the same size as the text, ~1.5x - 2x times larger.

Comment: I cant do it right now, but check 'dconf' I will try to answer later.

Comment: gnome-panel currently does not have proper support for HiDPI.